# Convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence for some subsequence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

An alternate proof to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269026/is-the-hypothesis-of-a-theorem-that-convergence-in-law-implies-convergence-in-pr) question requires below theorem.

---

Let $X$ be a random variable and $\left\{X_{n}\right\}$ be a sequence of random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

- $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ in probability if $\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_{n}-X\right|>\varepsilon\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.
- $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ a.s. if $\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X_{n}(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)\right\}\right)=1$.

Prove that $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ in probability implies there exists a subsequence $(X_{n_k})_k$ such that $X_{n_k} \rightarrow X$ a.s. as $k \to \infty$.

---

Could you check if my understanding is correct?

---

Let's characterize such $(X_{n_k})_k$. Let $f$ be a strictly decreasing function such that $\lim_{m \to \infty} f(m)=0$. We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
& X_{n_k} \to X \text{ a.s. as } k \to \infty \\
\iff & \mathbb P \left ( \{ \omega \mid X_{n_k} (\omega) \to X (\omega) \} \right ) = 1 \\
\iff & \mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb N^*} \bigcup_{M \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n_k \ge M} \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| \le f(m) \right \} \right ) = 1 \\
\iff & \mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb N^*} \bigcup_{M \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{k \ge M} \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| \le f(m) \right \} \right ) = 1, \quad k \to n_k \text{ is strictly increasing} \\
\iff & \mathbb P \left ( \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N^*} \bigcap_{M \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{k \ge M} \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > f(m) \right \} \right ) = 0 \\
\iff & \mathbb P \left ( \bigcap_{M \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{k \ge M} \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > f(m) \right \} \right ) = 0, \quad m \in \mathbb N^* \\
\iff & \mathbb P \left ( \limsup_k \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > f(m) \right \} \right ) = 0, \quad m \in \mathbb N^*.
\end{aligned}
$$

By Borel-Cantelli lemma , it suffices to choose $(n_k)$ and $f$ such that

$$\sum_{k} \mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > f(m) \right \} )  < \infty, \quad m \in \mathbb N^*.$$

The problem is to choose $n_k$ such that the inequality holds for all $m$. The idea is to fix the partition $g(0) > g(1) > \cdots > 0$ of $\mathbb R_+$ and control the quantity $\mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > g(i) \right \} )$. If $f(m) \ge g (i_0)$ for some $i_0 \in \mathbb N$, then $$\mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > f(m)  \right \} ) \le \mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > g (i_0) \right \} )$$ and thus $$\sum_{k} \mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > f(m)  \right \} ) \le \sum_{k} \mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > g (i_0) \right \} ).$$

To do so, we want to make $\sum_{k \ge K} \mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > g (i_0) \right \} ) < \infty$ for some $K$ big enough. We expect something like $$\sum_{k \ge K} \mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > g(k) \right \} ) < \infty$$ and $g(k) \le g (i_0)$ for all $k \ge K$. We know that $\sum_{k} 2^{-k} < \infty$, so we take $g: k \to 2^{-k}$ and $n_k$ such that $$\mathbb P ( \left \{ |X_{n_k} - X| > 2^{-k} \right \} ) < 2^{-k}.$$

Of course, the existence of such $n_k$ is guaranteed by the convergence in probability of $(X_k)$ to $X$. This completes the proof.